# Dictionary and list related query in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am pulling data from a data base and the ending code looks like:

```
x = col.find()    
for data in x:
        print(data)
```

And it is giving output like(A lot of dictionaries):

```
{'page_info': [{'client_id': '123.123.0', 'url': 'somewebsitehere.com', 'referer': 'false', 'language': 'en', 'meta_title': 'datahere', 'meta_description': False, 'meta_keywords': False, 'page_keywords': False, 'visit_info': [{'visit_date': '31/03/2021', 'session_info': [{'session_start': 'Wed, 31 Mar 2021 11:45:28 GMT', 'session_end': 'Wed, 31 Mar 2021 12:06:01 GMT', 'scroll_start': '0', 'scroll_end': '0'}]}], 'form_info': []}, {'client_id': '123.123.0', 'url': 'somewebsitehere.com', 'referer': 'false', 'language': 'en', 'meta_title': 'datahere', 'meta_description': False, 'meta_keywords': False, 'page_keywords': False, 'visit_info': [{'visit_date': '31/03/2021', 'session_info': [{'session_start': 'Wed, 31 Mar 2021 11:49:53 GMT', 'session_end': 'Wed, 31 Mar 2021 12:06:03 GMT', 'scroll_start': '0', 'scroll_end': '0'}, {'session_start': 'Wed, 31 Mar 2021 12:11:40 GMT', 'session_end': 'Wed, 31 Mar 2021 12:12:33 GMT', 'scroll_start': '0', 'scroll_end': '0'}]}], 'form_info': []}]}

{'page_info': [{'client_id': '123.123.0', 'url': 'somewebsitehere.com', 'referer': 'false', 'language': 'en', 'meta_title': 'datahere', 'meta_description': False, 'meta_keywords': False, 'page_keywords': False, 'visit_info': [{'visit_date': '31/03/2021', 'session_info': [{'session_start': 'Wed, 31 Mar 2021 11:45:28 GMT', 'session_end': 'Wed, 31 Mar 2021 12:06:01 GMT', 'scroll_start': '0', 'scroll_end': '0'}]}], 'form_info': []}, {'client_id': '123.123.0', 'url': 'somewebsitehere.com', 'referer': 'false', 'language': 'en', 'meta_title': 'datahere', 'meta_description': False, 'meta_keywords': False, 'page_keywords': False, 'visit_info': [{'visit_date': '31/03/2021', 'session_info': [{'session_start': 'Wed, 31 Mar 2021 11:49:53 GMT', 'session_end': 'Wed, 31 Mar 2021 12:06:03 GMT', 'scroll_start': '0', 'scroll_end': '0'}, {'session_start': 'Wed, 31 Mar 2021 12:11:40 GMT', 'session_end': 'Wed, 31 Mar 2021 12:12:33 GMT', 'scroll_start': '0', 'scroll_end': '0'}]}], 'form_info': []}]}
```

I am trying to make a data frame for that but firstly I need to have individual lists of items like:

```
client_id=["123.123.0","123.123.0"]
url=["somewebsitehere.com","somewebsitehere.com"]
```

and so on...

**How can I pull lists like this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the client ids and the urls as lists for **one dict at a time** inside the for loop you provided. Similarly, you can do the same for the rest of the keys of your interest.

```
client = []
url = []
x = col.find()    
for data in x: 
    for i in range(len(data['page_info'])):
        client_id.append(data['page_info'][i]['client_id'])
        urls.append(data['page_info'][i]['url'])
```

Comment: yes it is working but only for first dictionary ...there are 1000s of dictionary like this....I tried putting all these dictionaries in list as well like [(same dictionaries as above)] but not able to iterate over it ...I am new to programming and it is getting too complicated